# How to prevent Collection from outputting indexes to json?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

Code sample:

```
$x = collect(["a", "b", "c"]);
$x->toJson(); // => ["a","b","c"]
$x->reverse()->toJson(); // => {"2":"c","1":"b","0":"a"}
```

As you can see after I reverse the collection, json turns into an object with indexes as keys. How do I prevent that? How to output only values?

Comment: What would you expect the indexes of the JSON object to be?

Comment: Call `values()` to rekey the array before calling `toJson()`. Further explanation is provided in marked duplicate. `$x->reverse()->values()->toJson();`

Comment: Thanks, didn't find that question in search